# Drools Decision Table Multiple Parameters

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

I have a drools decision table with conditions `level="l0"` and `positiontype="Replacement"`. 
My excel looks like the below

My Code to set the parameters looks like

```
        Requirement requirement = new Requirement();
        requirement.setLevel("L0");
        requirement.setPositiontype("Replacement");
```

My excel file condition i am giving as requirementObject:

> Requirement    level==$param  positiontype==$param

When i set like above i get the below error:

> Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR,
>   path=rules.xls, line=8, column=0    text=[ERR 102] Line 8:14
>   mismatched input '==' in rule "Rule for Replacement"], Message [id=2,
>   level=ERROR, path=rules.xls, line=18, column=0    text=[ERR 102] Line
>   18:14 mismatched input '==' in rule "Rule for Budgeted"], Message
>   [id=3, level=ERROR, path=rules.xls, line=28, column=0    text=[ERR
>   102] Line 28:14 mismatched input '==' in rule "Rule for Additional"],
>   Message [id=4, level=ERROR, path=rules.xls, line=0, column=0
>   text=Parser returned a null Package]]

Please help me fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the excel file should as follows :

Requirement(level == $param);
Requirement(positiontype == $param );

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Drools decision table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFFjy.png)

Please reffer the image as you can see && is used for the same